# Get IndexOf Second int record in a sorted List in C#

Tags: c#, list, indexof

I am having problem while trying to get First and Second **Record** (not second highest/lowest **integer**) Index from a sorted List. Lets say that list consists of three records that in order are like this: 0, 0, 1.

I tried like this:

```
int FirstNumberIndex = MyList.IndexOf(MyList.OrderBy(item => item).Take(1).ToArray()[0]); //returns first record index, true
int SecondNumberIndex = MyList.IndexOf(MyList.OrderBy(item => item).Take(2).ToArray()[1]); //doesn't seem to work
```

As I explained, I am trying to get the indexes of first two zeros (they are not necessarily in ascending order before the sort) and not of zero and 1.
 So if there was a list {0, 2, 4, 0} I need to get Indexes 0 and 3. But this may apply to any number that is smallest and repeats itself in the List.
However, it must also work when the smallest value does not repeat itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SecondNumberIndex is set to 0 because

```
MyList.OrderBy(item => item).Take(2).ToArray()[1] == 0
```

then you get

```
 MyList.IndexOf(0)
```

that finds the first occurence of 0. 0 is equal to every other 0. So every time you ask for IndexOf(0), the very first 0 on the list gets found.

You can get what you want by using that sort of approach:

```
int FirstNumberIndex = MyList.IndexOf(0); //returns first record index, true
int SecondNumberIndex = MyList.IndexOf(0, FirstNumberIndex  + 1 ); //will start search next to last ocurrence
```

From your code I guess you confuse some kind of "instance equality" with regular "equality".
Int is a simple type, IndexOf will not search for ocurrence of *your specific instance of* 0.
Keep in mind that this code, even if we will move in our thoughts to actual objects:

```
MyList.OrderBy(item => item).Take(2).ToArray()[1]
```

will not necessarily return equal objects in their original relative order from the input list.

**EDIT**

This cannot be adopted for general case, for getting indexes of ordered values from the original, unordered list.

If you are searching for indexes of any number of equal values, then setting bigger and bigger offset for the second parameter of IndexOf is OK.
But, let's consider a case when there are no duplicates. Such approach will work only when the input list is actually ordered ;)

You can preprocess your input list to have pairs (value = list[i],idx =  i), then sort that pairs by value and then iterate over sorted pairs and print idx-es

Comment: exactly this is my problem.

Comment: One question. you have used 0 in MyList.IndexOf(0); Does that stand for record value? If so, I could change it for MyList.OrderBy getting first record. true?

Comment: In general - no. When you want to get, for sorted list,  a list of their indexes on original, input list, this approach is not really good to start. It was rather to explain the reason it failed to meet your expectations. Give me a second to edit.

Comment: And at last, as I am going to test it out now, i will get indexes of two zeros or zero and 1(if there were no two zeros).

Comment: Yes, the thing is I don't really know yet what the two smallest integers might be and whether these two will be two identical size int numbers or not.

Comment: Will it work if I sort the list beforehand and create new, sorted list?

Comment: @positiveperspective then your case is pointless. You loose info of original indexes.

Comment: Tough thing, seems that I found what to do for the rest of the evening as this is new thing to me.

Comment: Your last part of solution is clear and think this will work. Thanks. I will get back soon.

Comment: Brilliant. it works like a charm. I did exactly what you said: I converted list to List<int[]> where first element stands for value[i] and second for i, then I sorted by first value, skipped one, got FirstOrDefault and picked ElementAt(1) . This way I extracted index of the second value, even if the value is equal to first in order. Thank you.

Comment: Nice to hear. I hope that this was not an assignment, cos by my edit I did not let you think of the solution on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You, probably, are asking about something like this:

```
var list = new List<int>{0,0,1}; 
var result = list.Select((val,i)=> new {value = val, idx = i}).Where(x=>x.value == 0);
foreach(var r in result) //anonymous type enumeration
    Console.WriteLine(r.idx);
```

Comment: so this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can try user FindIndex.

```
var MyList = new List<int>() {3, 5, 1, 2, 4};
int firsIndex = MyList.FindIndex(a => a == MyList.OrderBy(item => item).Take(1).ToArray()[0]);
int secondIndex = MyList.FindIndex(a => a == MyList.OrderBy(item => item).Take(2).ToArray()[1]);
```

Comment: will it work for two smallest records that have same value?

Comment: int secondIndex = MyList.FindLastIndex(a => a == MyList.OrderBy(item => item).Take(2).ToArray()[1]);

Comment: that one still seems to return 0 as index for the second record index

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the offset of the first occurrence, then use `IndexOf` on the list after skipping the offset.

```
int offset = ints.IndexOf(0) + 1;
int secondIndex = ints.Skip(offset).ToList().IndexOf(0) + offset;
```

Comment: quite complicated. IndexOf has overloaded version with startIndex parameter.